# quicklooksatellite is blocking trash files

Tags: macos, finder, trash

I can't empty Trash folder. Some of files there are "in use". And it happens all the time.

> The operation can’t be completed because the item “blabla.xlsx” is in use.

I don't have any applications with these files. I don't have Finder with this folder open. And I didn't.

When I launch "What's Keeping Me?" utility, it says, that this file is opened in "QuickLookSatellite".

Is it possible to prevent?

OSX El Captain 10.11.3

Comment: Did you use QuickLook to preview those files or folders ?

Comment: @PratikaRana Maybe before they got deleted, certainly not after.

Comment: If you use QuickLook to preview a file or folder and you delete it afterwards, it will dsiplay the message that the files/folders are in use when emptying the trash. The only solution then is to use "Delete Immediately" within the trash.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about preventing it, but you can certainly try:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.Trash/*
```

You may be prompted for your password. The command will forcibly get rid of everything in your trash bin.

Comment: Thank you for advice, but it sounds like a workaround, not a solution. I get this problem all the time...

Comment: It is indeed a workaround. If you're getting this problem frequently, try Console and search for quicklook